# i am getting issue in stopping form submission event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, ng-bind-html

Guys i found a problem in stopping form submit. I have two fields of username and password all i want to show alert and stopping form submission if the username and password is same. Here is my code

```
<form name="myform"ng-submit="checked()" action="change_credintls" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
     <input type="text"ng-model="username"name="username"class="form-control"maxlength="20"  placeholder="ENTER NEW USERNAME"Required > 
     <input type="text"name="password"ng-model="pass"class="form-control"maxlength="20"  placeholder="ENTER NEW PASSWORD"Required >  
     <input style="border-radius:0px;"type="submit" CLASS="btn btn-primary btn-sm"value="CHANGE CREDIANTLS">
</form>
```

here is my angular code

```
  <script>
     var app= angular.module('myapp',[]);
     app.controller('mycntrl',function ($scope){
        $scope.checked= function(myform)
        { 
           if($scope.username == $scope.pass)
           {
             alert("Your user name and password can not be same");
             return false;
           }
        }

    });
  </script>
```

The alert is working but i am unable to stop form submission

Comment: how can i stop form submission?

Comment: removed but problem still exist.

Comment: use event.preventDefault(); instead of return false

Answer (score 1):

try this.

**HTML**

```
   <form name="myform"ng-submit="checked($event)" action="change_credintls" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
 <input type="text"ng-model="username"name="username"class="form-control"maxlength="20"  placeholder="ENTER NEW USERNAME"Required > 
 <input type="text"name="password"ng-model="pass"class="form-control"maxlength="20"  placeholder="ENTER NEW PASSWORD"Required >  
 <input style="border-radius:0px;"type="submit" CLASS="btn btn-primary btn-sm"value="CHANGE CREDIANTLS">
```

**Anguler**

```
    <script>
 var app= angular.module('myapp',[]);
 app.controller('mycntrl',function ($scope){
    $scope.checked= function($event,myform)
    { 
       if($scope.username == $scope.pass)
       {
         //alert("Your user name and password can not be same");
         $event.preventDefault()
       }
    }

});
```

it should work for you.